# Are there better/easier flows for users to install an app instead of linking it to the App Store/Google Play?

Tags: website-design, app, download, flow

If I have a website that wants users to install an app, what are my options?

I'm currently aware you can use the respective badges, https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/ and https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#downloadOnAppstore

As well as SMS texting or QR codes...

What are your opinions about the above methods and do you have any other  recommendations?

Comment: The app stores for Android and Mac are gatekeepers of the respective OSes. That means, they would want you to put your app in their store and share it with your users as a standardized badge. That standardization offers some trust and comfort level. I guess that is the best approach to go about it as of today.

Comment: My experience of trying to install the "Hoopla" app from my library on to my android phone, Kindle tablet, another tablet, and Fiancee's computer was horrid. Then when I chose a book, I had to go to Amazon to borrow it! I was afraid I would have to pay! Someone, please make all of this easier! It is just a circus now. Nontechnical people would never get it to work on their own. I did only because I was pigheaded and even did things I thought were wrong and made no sense, until finally, it just started working! Awful!

Answer (score 2):

Unless your user has developer credentials I think anyone who downloads your app is contractually required to download it through one of the app stores. Thus I think you are required to redirect the user to the appropriate store.

It IS POSSIBLE to set up a link by which users can download and install an app, but it's kind of a hack and it is probably grounds for revoking a developer license.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of app. Is it a Android app, you don't need to point them to the store as they can download the .apk file themself. You can host the file on your website. The downside is you don't receive any download information or where they come from.

As for iOS, no other way then user searches in the App Store, SMS code with link or go via the 'app store' badge on your site. The last one is most famous for visitors.